# AWS S3 promise meteor

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-s3, promise, ecmascript-6

So, I'm using `AWS = Npm.require('aws-sdk');` from Amazon.

Apparently promise are implemented. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property

See my functions (Server):

```
s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: "2006-03-01" });

bucketExists = (bucket) => {
  check(bucket, String);

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket
  };

  return s3.putObject({Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key'}).promise();
};


Meteor.methods({
  addPhoto(userId, photo) {
    check(userId, String);
    check(photo, Object);

    bucketExists(userId)
    .then(
      function(value) {
        console.log("Contents: " + value);
      })
    .catch(function(reason) {
      console.error("Error or timeout", reason);
    });
  }
});
```

Exeption:

```
Exception while invoking method 'addPhoto' TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'promise'.
```

WTF

So, I try without call promise(). Like that:

```
bucketExists = (bucket) => {
  check(bucket, String);

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket
  };

  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      s3.waitFor('bucketExists', params, (err, res) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(res);
      });
    });
};
```

But nothing appear. I start with ES6. So please help.

Thanks

Comment: What version of the aws-sdk are you using?

Comment: The last one I guess 2.2.42. But I think have solved my problem. So the promise was good, for the promise function of Amazon it's still fuzzy.

Comment: You need to use version 2.3+ to get the built in AWS promises.